# Microsoft Access 2013 Calculated Control Syntax

Tags: ms-access, syntax

I'm trying to make a simply form that contains certain yes/no questions. Each form has a second hidden column that contains a bit value, 0 or 1, to that stores the answer. My problem is the syntax necessary to add the values and total them at the end of the form. [image]

I have tried adding the following code in the calculated control for the sum text box:

```
=SUM([Combo_A] + [Combo_B] + [Combo_C]) 
[Combo_A] + [Combo_B] + [Combo_C]
```

In both cases I get errors, and I can't find the proper syntax on the following tutorials:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-expression-893d516c-86f8-43e7-b9c1-d38c02678e5b#__toc288566552

http://www.gcflearnfree.org/access2013/creating-calculated-fields-and-totals-rows/1/

http://ms-access-tips.blogspot.com/2011/07/calculated-controls.html

I recognize it is a simple syntax error, I just can't crack it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the 0 or 1 value to the combo box as another hidden column. Make that column the bound column. Now you can add them up.

= Val( [Combo_A] ) + Val( [Combo_B] ) + Val( [Combo_C] )

Comment: That works, to an extent. Like I described earlier, I'm guessing because of the strings in the first column, it merely concatenates the equation as strings, rather than addition. A response such as "YYNY" is recorded as "1101" instead of "3." Any idea how to reiterate in the formula that it should be treated as an int? =Val(equation) and =Int(equation) don't work.

Comment: Did you try Val([Combo_A]) + Val([Combo_B]) + Val([Combo_C]) ?

Comment: That's correct, although interestingly enough when I tried =Val([Combo_A] + ...) It gave me an error. Interesting syntax. Thank you Minty!

Answer (score 0):

Control Source property for Sum text box should be

```
=[Combo_A] + [Combo_B] + [Combo_C]
```

I assume, that [Combo_X] text boxes contain 0 and 1.

Comment: Thanks, that works about halfway. Instead of an int or sum, it concatenates the answers so for a sample of YNN I get an calculated control answer of "100", or YNY is calculated as "101." Any idea of how to treat one side of the column (The Yes/No) as a string, but the right column with the number values as int's, so it will be added and not concatenated?